# ADFS certificate-based authentication using machine (not user) certificates

Tags: active-directory, adfs

I have an environment running Windows 2012 R2 ADFS. We've set up certificate-based authentication using client certificates (user certificates) and it's working as expected. They would like to use machine certificates instead of user certificates for the certificate-based authentication. Is this possible and, if so, how do I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Who is they and why do they want to install user certificates in the machine personal store? Users don't have permission to the private key for certificates in the machine store.

Comment: What are you trying to authenticate with? VPN/website/domain controller?